# Remove/Hide a Widget on a Custom Template

Tags: theme-development, menus, customization, widgets

i want to make a custom template using Genesis.. 
I added a custom Menu just by adding a widget on WIDGETS section and placed it on the top right side of the page. But i want it to be removed in a specific template ... How can i do that??

```
<?php
/*
Template Name:  No Menu - Full Page
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>

<div id="featured">
  <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php genesis_before_content_sidebar_wrap(); ?>
<div id="content-sidebar-wrap">
  <?php genesis_before_content(); ?>
  <div id="content" class="hfeed">
    <?php genesis_before_loop(); ?>
    <?php genesis_loop(); ?>
    <?php genesis_after_loop(); ?>
  </div>
  <!-- end #content -->
  <?php genesis_after_content(); ?>
</div>
<!-- end #content-sidebar-wrap -->
<?php genesis_after_content_sidebar_wrap(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I guess i just dont know the code..  but i want this to be removed in my custom template `genesis_header_right`

using Inspect Element, I copied the HTML version of the whole header

```
    <div id="header">
      <div class="wrap">
        <div id="title-area">
          <div class="genesis_hook" title="By default, this hook outputs the site title, within the header area. It uses the user-specified SEO settings to build the site title markup appropriately.">genesis_site_title</div>
          <h1 id="title"><a href="http://localhost/mysite/" title="Title">Title</a></h1>
          <div class="genesis_hook" title="By default, this hook outputs the site description, within the header area. It uses the user-specified SEO settings to build the site description markup appropriately.">genesis_site_description</div>
          <p id="description">Just another WordPress site</p>
        </div>
        <!-- end #title-area -->
        <div class="widget-area">
          <div class="genesis_hook" title="This hook executes immediately before the Header Right widget area inside div.widget-area.">genesis_header_right</div>
          <div id="nav_menu-2" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
            <div class="widget-wrap">
              <div class="menu-top-menu-container">
                <ul id="menu-top-menu" class="menu genesis-nav-menu sf-js-enabled">
                  <li id="menu-item-172" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-home menu-item-172"><a href="http://localhost/mysite">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end .widget-area --></div>
      <!-- end .wrap --></div>
```

this is the code i want to remove

```
            <div class="widget-area">
              <div class="genesis_hook" title="This hook executes immediately before the Header Right widget area inside div.widget-area.">genesis_header_right</div>
              <div id="nav_menu-2" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
                <div class="widget-wrap">
                  <div class="menu-top-menu-container">
                    <ul id="menu-top-menu" class="menu genesis-nav-menu sf-js-enabled">
                      <li id="menu-item-172" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-home menu-item-172"><a href="http://localhost/mysite">Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

I tried adding this below the get header code

`unregister_sidebar( 'header-right' );`

Didnt do anything

Answer (score 1):

The menu is most likely part of the file header.php, which is called from get_header(). To alter the header just for your custom template, you may create another header file (e.g. header-no-menu.php), and call it using get_header('no-menu'). Here's a link to some documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header
Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok ill read that, for now i made an alternative using CSS display: none

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ( ! is_page_template( 'your-specific-template.php' ) { ?>
    <div class="widget-area">
        ⋮
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template